# How do I crawl and collect data from a webpage in R?

Tags: r

I need some data from [GSM3513973](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM3513973) as a webpage. If you click on that(GSM3513973), you can see some fields such as 'menopausal_status'. Now, I need to read this webpage and extract some fields such as the below data frame:

```
Acssess No.  sample_id     menopausal_status    subtype_pam50   subtype_nmc
GSM3513973  OB_15_0074_1    Premenopausal         LumB             ER+
GSM3513974  OB_15_0080_2    Postmenopausal        LumB             TN
GSM3513975  OB_15_0107_2    Premenopausal         Basal            ER+
GSM3513976  OB_15_0107_3    Premenopausal         Basal            TN
GSM3513977  OB_15_0119_1    Premenopausal         Basal            TN
GSM3513978  OB_15_0139_1    Premenopausal         Basal            TN
GSM3513979  OB_15_0139_2    Premenopausal         Basal            ER+
GSM3513980  OB_15_0139_3    Premenopausal         Normal           TN
GSM3513981  OB_15_0157_1    Premenopausal         Basal            TN
GSM3513982  OB_15_0157_3    Premenopausal         Basal            TN
```

how can I prepare this data in R?

Comment: I would suggest packages "rvest" and "Rcrawler" for these types of tasks. 
Too much info available on the topic of "Webscraping with R" to pack into a single answer to one question imo.

Comment: Please remember to include what you have tried. We should be able to reproduce the problem you are having and see you research. There is guidance under [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The data format you show in your question is not all on this one page. You can get the data in the main section you describe like this:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

url <- "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM3513973"
xpath <- "//table/tr/td[text() = 'Characteristics']/following-sibling::td[1]"

result <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_node(xpath = xpath) %>% 
  xml_contents() %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  `[`(nzchar(.)) %>% 
  strsplit(":") %>% 
  {do.call(rbind, .)} %>% 
  trimws() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(c("Characteristic", "Value"))

head(result)
#>      Characteristic         Value
#> 1            gender        Female
#> 2               age   50.99722222
#> 3 menopausal_status Premenopausal
#> 4 bc_family_history            No
#> 5      brca1_status  Not Detected
#> 6      brca2_status      Detected
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear @allan-cameron thanks. you define:                                                         
 xpath <- "//table/tr/td[text() = 'Characteristics']/following-sibling::td[1]" .              
 how do you define tha value of xpath? it is default definition?

Comment: @Mohammad XPath is a query language for navigating xml and html. That XPath picks out the particular html element that contains the text you specified. I had to look at the page's html to figure out the XPath. There are lots of free online resources to read more about XPath. This will help if you plan to do a lot of web scraping.